# jQuery Sortable Sibling Grouping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am wondering if its possible to group sortable items if a class exist for the next siblings. Here is a stripped down version of what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="itemClass">A</div>
<div class="itemClass">B</div>
<div class="itemClass groupWith">C</div>
<div class="itemClass">D</div>
```

I need it so that if you drag B, C goes with it. A, C and D would sort individually as normal. The groups rule is that if it doesn't have a groupWith and the immediate siblings have a groupWith class, keep them together.

I'd like to avoid having to make the group with as a child, but if there is no other way, I will have to look at that.

Is there any way to do this? I suppose the worse case scenario is that I move the those items after, but I would like the sortable to be dragging the group, not just the single item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no nice way to do this (that I know of).

The way I would go about it is adding a attribute to B that has the id or something to identify C. Then in the .update function in the sortable you can check if the sorted element has this attribute and if so detach then append C.

some thing like

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui){
    if (ui.item.attr('connectedTo')){
      $('#'+ui.item.attr('connectedTo')).detach().insertAfter(ui.item);
    }
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="sortable">
<div id="A">A</div>
<div id="B" connectedTo="C">B</div>
<div id="C">C</div>
<div id="D">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that doing it after might be the only way. I don't have to create a connectedTo. I can simply store the nextUntil(':not(.groupWith)') item and move those on update, but its the same idea, so I'll mark this as correct.